# Fill color inside UIBezierPath

Tags: iphone, uibezierpath

I want to fill color inside a graph using UIBezierPath. Till now I have used following code:

```
NSMutableArray *graphData=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2013-06-26",@"46", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2013-06-27",@"37", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2013-06-28",@"96", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2013-06-29",@"29", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2013-06-30",@"29", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"2013-07-01",@"24", nil], nil];
    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];

    [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10, kGraphBottom-[[[graphData objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1]floatValue])];

    for (int i = 1; i < graphData.count; i++)
    {
        [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(10+50* (i), kGraphBottom-[[[graphData objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1]floatValue])];

    }

    [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10+50*graphData.count , kGraphBottom)];
    [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10 , kGraphBottom)];
    [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(10 , kGraphBottom-[[[graphData objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:1]floatValue])];
     [aPath closePath];
    [aPath fill];
    [aPath stroke];
```

The output that i am getting is like the image shown below:[image: Graph]

How can i fill the color between the graph and the x,y axis?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: edited the question.please read

Comment: @Herçules: thanks do u have any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are not closing your path properly, hence the straight line between the first and last points.  You should use `addLineToPoint` for the last three points not just `moveToPoint` and then I think you will be there.

Comment: I cant use addlinetopoint as i dont want to add a line there...i hope u  get it

Comment: addLineToPoint simply moves the invisible cursor, but doesn't add anything to your path so won't do anything.  If you want to just fill everything under the graph then you will need to use addLineToPoint from the last point vertically to the axis, horizontally along the x-axis and then vertically up to the first point which is what you have with the moveToPoint.  If you just want the top of the graph to show in black then stroke your path without adding these points or closing the path first.  Then add 3 lines and fill it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, you want to stroke that path, but fill a different area (The area between your path and the axis).

You'll have to use two paths for that. The one you are drawing right now for the stroke and another one for the fill. Build both paths at the same time, but start the fill path from the origin of you coordinate system and add a line to the beginning of you graph. Keep adding lines to both paths and at the end add a line down to the x-axis for the fill path, close the fill path and you're done.